# Login Script working local but not on live environment

Tags: php

I seem to have a problem with a login script, it works on a local php dev box, but not on my live environment, i'm assuming i'm missing something can anyone advise further?

```
<?php
$user = $_POST["swtorun"];
$pass = $_POST["swtorpw"];

// Generate hash
$enc_pwd = hash('sha256', $pass);

// Connect to DataBase
include('../../settings.php');

$conn = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
$db = mysql_select_db($database, $conn);

// mySql Query users
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$user' and password='$enc_pwd'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result); // number of results (should be 1)

if($count==1){
// initiate session
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged'] = "1";
echo "you are now logged in, return to the <a href=\"../../index.php\">index</a>";
} else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please define "does not work". Are there any errors?

Comment: on dev box it works fine, on live I get my "Wrong Username and Password" output.

Comment: => http://xkcd.com/327/: Please USE `mysql_real_escape_string()`!

Comment: Show all errors, but most likely, the mysql connection fails (check whether `$conn` is a resource), and by all means, `require` things like settings that you absolutely need.

Comment: Have you verified that the query succeeded by fetching the row from `$result`?

Comment: What php version on live server? req. for hash() are `PHP 5 >= 5.1.2, PECL hash >= 1.1`

Comment: phpinfo reports version as 5.3.8, @Michael how can I verify the query

Comment: @ComFreek - I was using real escape string at first, but since I could not get it to work that way I took that particular code out

Comment: when using mysql_real_escape_string($pass) I get the following message Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'tfclanco'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/tfclanco/public_html/swtor/install/setup.php on line 15

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/tfclanco/public_html/swtor/install/setup.php on line 15
Proceed to next step: create databases.

Comment: @PrivateSniper Just check it contains what you expect with something like: `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); var_dump($row);`

Comment: ok, so interesting thing is that on my dev box, the result is resource(7, mysql result)  but on live server it is bool(false), so I suppose this is a connection issue?

Comment: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'tfclanco'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/tfclanco/public_html/swtor/install/setup.php on line 15  is a connection issue.

Comment: @PrivateSniper Maybe your connection fails, try to add this `mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());`.

Comment: Thanks ComFreek, this particular step wouldn't have made any difference, as the connection was working fine, however it did highlight the problem. the actual solution was to change my table name as I had mis-spelled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that I had the table name capitalised on one script, but lower case on this script, hence the query failed and so did the code relying on it, I have since fixed the other script to create the table in lower case.

thanks to all commments left in helping troubleshooting issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add `session_start();` to the topmost part of your PHP code.

Comment: That wont help his error of wrong username password. The if() block is only checking if $count == 1. You can call session_start(); anytime before headers are sent to the browser.